# Geofencing not woking after long idle time (sleep mode) of the iPhone (iOS 6 and 7)

Tags: ios, iphone, geolocation, geofencing

Geofencing is working when the app is in background. But if i put the device in sleep mode for long time and start moving with the device then Geofencing is not working at all.

And i also wanted to know all the network connection(3G,Wifi) are disconnected when the device in sleep mode. What is the application status after long idle time (sleep mode).

Thanks in advance..